# How to POST/PUT Web API asp net core One to Many relationships?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

New to Web API and also to C# so still trying to learn.

I've gotten to the point where I can display this

```
 [{"name":"myname","birthday":"11111","nickname":"mynickname","phoneNumbers":[{"type":"phone","phone":"work","number":"1231231234"},{"type":"phone","phone":"cell","number":"4564654567"}]}]
```

But when I try to update the "number", it changes the "phoneNumbers" to null, and same when I try to POST something new.

So now I'm not sure where the problem is...
The repository?

```
 public void Add(Contacts item)
 {
     ContactList.Add(item);
 }
 public void Update(Contacts item)
 {
     var itemToUpdate = ContactList.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Birthday == item.Birthday);
     if (itemToUpdate != null)
     {
         itemToUpdate.Name = item.Name;
         itemToUpdate.Birthday = item.Birthday;
         itemToUpdate.Nickname = item.Nickname;
         itemToUpdate.PhoneNumbers = item.PhoneNumbers;
     }
```

Or my controller?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Contacts item)
    {
        //
        ContactsRepo.Add(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetContacts", new { Controller = "Contacts", id = item.Birthday }, item);

    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Update(string id, [FromBody] Contacts item)
    {
        //
        ContactsRepo.Update(item);
        return new NoContentResult();
    }
```

Or something completely different?

Edit: Contact class

```
public class Contacts
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the code for your `Contacts` class.

Comment: Can you also include the model `Contacts` here?

Comment: Edited and included the contacts class

Comment: If you set a break point inside `Update` action method, do you see `PhoneNumbers` inside `Contacts`?

Comment: Yes I still see PhoneNumbers inside Contacts